# Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: postgresql, database

> After some time the Postgres database stopped working.
>
> when I try to enter the command, `psql` produces an error
>
> ```
> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>         Is the server running locally and accepting
>         connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
> ```
>
> If I do
>
> ```
> sudo su - postgres
> psql
> ```
>
> then the error is `Use of uninitialized value`
>
> ```
> $gid in getgrgid at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 762.
> psql: could not look up local user ID 109: Permission denied
> ```
>
> Googling does not help ((

(*translated using Google Translate*)

---

*Original text:*

С пустя какое-то время БД Postgres перестала работать

при попытке ввести команду psql выдает ошибку
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Если делать
sudo su - postgres
psql
то ошибка 
Use of uninitialized value $gid in getgrgid at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 762.
psql: could not look up local user ID 109: Permission denied

прогуглил все ничего не помогает((